# Special characters show as 'BLOB' when typing SELECT CHAR(128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137);

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL 8.0.31 and learning using the Sakila dataset. I tried typing
SELECT CHAR(128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137); but the result shows
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elrFe.png)

I also checked the default character set and it is 'utf8mb4'

I don't see a lot of answers and I'm a beginner. Please help

Edit:

I am expecting this result:
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrfAO.png)

This is taken from Learning SQL book by Alan B.

From the Book:

the following examples show the
location of the accented characters along with other special characters, such as currency symbols:

mysql> SELECT CHAR(128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137);

result:  Çüéâäàåçêë

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] to add a transcription of your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Comment: 'This is taken from Learning SQL book by Alan B.' - can you add the relevant bits to the question please. Also sakila is a sample database - what version did you import , what table are you querying and what does your query look like, and windows or linux, mysql version - ie question is too vague.

Comment: Using MySQL 8.0.31 version. Sakila sample database version is 1.3 and I am using Windows. 

I also edited my post.

Comment: I ran into the same problem as yours, is there any chance you've got a solution?

Answer (score 0):

"BLOB" is a datatype used in databases to contain *binary* data (that is, not representable as text).

The string of characters you built is not representable in the default charset (UTF8), so MySQL does not know how to print it out, and just says is binary content.

The example in the book you are reading surely is assuming the default DB charset is ASCII. Since it is not, you must specify it:

```
SELECT CHAR(128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137 USING ascii);
```

Comment: Hi. I am expecting this result:

Çüéâäàåçêë as shown in Learning SQL by Alan B.  Please check my edited post for the screenshot from the book.

Comment: OK. Read my edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work on my end